# Is setting a value outside of both state and props in a React component an anti-pattern?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

In nearly all conversations about data and React, Props and State are the two most common concepts. However, I've noticed that there is technically a third way of setting data in a React component. More specifically, you can set a value by setting a value to `this`.

For example, the code below I have set three values. One value on State, one value in the default Props, and the other on `this`. I can print all three of them.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      stateSecret: "foo"
    };
    this.otherSecret = "bar";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.stateSecret}
        <br />
        {this.otherSecret}
        <br />
        {this.props.propsSecret}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.defaultProps = {
  propsSecret: "baz"
};

export default App;
```

In general, I want to know if I am I committing to an anti-pattern by setting a value to `this`. Is this something I should avoid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not an anti-pattern, it's generally okay.

If it's a constant you can even define it outside (4th way :D) like:

```
const otherSecret = "bar";
class App extends Component {

}
```

Generally speaking:

- Define it in the state if it will change by some logic defined in your component
- Define it in the parent and pass as prop if it will change by a logic defined in the parent

One more thing to consider, when the value of a prop or state changes, the component triggers a change and it runs the render() again, so if you want to reflect the changes, you should declare it in the state or as a prop from the parent component.